# OData search in associated tables of a SAP Core Data Service

Tags: odata, abap, cds

I'm working with SAP Core Data Services (CDS) and struggling with OData queries in fields that are part of associated view/tables.

Here's a minimal (not) working example:

### Table Definitions

I created two tables named "ZTABLE_A" and "ZTABLE_B".

ZTABLE_A contains two columns ("COLUMN_A1", "COLUMN_A2") and so does ZTABLE_B ("COLUMN_B1", "COLUMN_B2").

All columns have the built-in datatype CHAR, length 50. COLUMN_A1 and COLUMN_B1 are primary keys.

[image: se11 screenshot of ZTABLE_A]

[image: se11 screenshot of ZTABLE_B]

### Example Data in Tables

To demonstrate my problem, I'm adding a few lines of sample data:

#### Data in ZTABLE_A

```
+-----------------------------+
| COLUMN_A1 (key) | COLUMN_A2 |
+-----------------+-----------+
|        A        |     X     |
|        B        |     Y     |
|        C        |     Z     |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

#### Data in ZTABLE_B

```
+-----------------------------+
| COLUMN_B1 (key) | COLUMN_B2 |
+-----------------+-----------+
|       FOO       |     X     |
|       BAR       |     X     |
|       TEST      |   ASDFC   |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

Using Eclipse Photon, I created the corresponding CDS views in ZMY_PACKAGE->Core Data Services->Data Definitions.

#### Definition of ZCDS_A (with association)

```sql
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZCDSVIEW_A'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'Obligatory Label A'
@OData.publish: true
@Search.searchable: true
define view ZCDS_A as select from ztable_a
association [1..*] to ZCDS_B on ztable_a.column_a2 = ZCDS_B.column_b2
{
   @Search.defaultSearchElement: true
   key ztable_a.column_a1,
   @Search.defaultSearchElement: true
   ztable_a.column_a2,
   @Search.defaultSearchElement: true
   ZCDS_B
}
```

#### Definition of ZCDS_B (simple)

```sql
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZCDSVIEW_B'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'Obligatory Label B'
@OData.publish: true
@Search.searchable: true
define view ZCDS_B as select from ztable_b
{
   @Search.defaultSearchElement: true
   key column_b1,
   @Search.defaultSearchElement: true
   column_b2
}
```

After activating both CDS, I added ZCDS_A as data references using the transaction code `segw` and generated the runtime objects by clicking the red/white circle. Next, I opened the SAP Gateway Client by right-clicking the service. Now, I'm able to query ZCDS_A using OData.

### OData Queries

#### Plain Expanded Query

If I expand to ZCDS_B, I receive a result, as expected.

**OData query:** `/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMY_PACKAGE/ZCDS_A?$format=json&$expand=toZCDS_B`

It contains all entries of ZTABLE_A and two entries of ZTABLE_B which are nested in the entry with the value 'X' of ZTABLE_A in COLUMN_A2.

```
[
  {
    "__metadata": { ... },
    "column_a1": "A",
    "column_a2": "X",
    "toZCDS_B": {
      "results": [
        {
          "__metadata": "__metadata": { ... },
          "column_b1": "BAR",
          "column_b2": "X"
        },
        {
          "__metadata": {... },
          "column_b1": "FOO",
          "column_b2": "X"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "__metadata": { ... },
    "column_a1": "B",
    "column_a2": "Y",
    "toZCDS_B": {
      "results": []
    }
  },
  {
    "__metadata": { ... },
    "column_a1": "C",
    "column_a2": "Z",
    "toZCDS_B": {
      "results": []
    }
  }
]
```

#### Search in Fields of ZTABLE_A

It's also possible to use the query parameter `search` (without a leading '$').

**OData query:** `/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMY_PACKAGE/ZCDS_A?$format=json&$expand=toZCDS_B&search=B`

As expected, this returns a list with only one result from ZTABLE_A which contains 'B' as a value. This entry in ZTABLE_A is not associated with any entry in ZTABLE_B.

```
{
  "__metadata" : { ... },
  "column_a1" : "B",
  "column_a2" : "Y",
  "toZCDS_B" : {
    "results" : [
     ]
  }
}
```

#### Problem: Search in Fields of ZTABLE_B

Now, here's the tricky part: I would like to query fields of the associated ZCDS_B / ZTABLE_B while querying ZCDS_A.

**OData query:** `/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMY_PACKAGE/ZCDS_A?$format=json&$expand=toZCDS_B&search=FOO`

I'd expect a result like:

{

```
  "__metadata": { ... },
  "column_a1": "A",
  "column_a2": "X",
  "toZCDS_B": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {... },
        "column_b1": "FOO",
        "column_b2": "X"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But only an empty list is returned:

```
"results" : [ ]
```

Where is the problem? I marked both the views and their single fields as searchable using the `@Search.searchable: true` annotation or the `@Search.defaultSearchElement: true` respectively. Isn't it possible to query nested tables?

ABAP Version 7.50